# Is it correct to ask SQL optimization questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question on dba.stackexchange.com:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245377/optimize-a-postgresql-database-view-query
The community there is smaller though, so I was wondering if it's 'legal' to post that sort of question on Stack Overflow, because it also deals with views in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Note: the fact that you use ruby to extract the results from your database, doesn't make it automatically on topic for SO.

Comment: The DBA folks are good. Really good. The DBA SE is essentially a SO + ServerFault, but only for databases. Here quality is more important as quantity, i.e. the probability that you get a good answer, is high on the DBA. They are also more friendly community. But eliminate the whole ruby thing, they are good in DBs and not in ruby.

Comment: Simple preliminary research effort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+optimization . Such questions are asked and they are also answered. They do not receive upvotes as frequently though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not a total blanket answer to this. It really depends more on *endeavor* than anything else. If you're encountering a query path that's unexpectedly suboptimal, or you know it's a bottleneck and you just can't understand why, then Stack Overflow is very likely to help. Slowness is a bug if it kills performance or prevents other features from working, and performance is a feature.

If it's more "I feel like there's theoretically some room for improvement here" then you're veering away from having a real *problem* so to speak, and more into the realm of just having a theory. That's .. where Stack Overflow probably isn't the best resource (BUT COULD BE - it depends).

If you know that it's a major pain point, then a query along with the corresponding structure kind of just serves as the MCVE. Additionally, if you think you're encountering strange behavior from a certain DB server (like others might question the output of a compiler) - SO is probably fine.

If you're just trying to slim down a query ... you might want to explore using DBA. If you've put out a good-faith effort to meet the criteria as defined in the respective help centers, folks will generally help you end up in the right place.

Note: Don't cross post unless you're essentially asking two different questions using the same query to show the problem. In other words, if you ask on DBA *and* Stack Overflow, the questions should be fundamentally different in terms of the answer you'd like to receive.

As far as duplicates in general go - search the site you intend to ask on and be receptive to people letting you know the answer eluded you because of the terms you used. A question having been asked on DBA doesn't mean it can't be asked on SO (or the reverse), but again, make sure the answers to existing questions are fundamentally different from what you need, and try to make it clear.